# Sql Query I don't understand that uses a loop to find certain databases. I need it to search in a slightly different way

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

I hope its okay to simply ask a question when I don't understand how to go about something and don't know how to figure it out. Otherwise, I apologize for the question.

A coworker sent me a query he uses as an example of something I'm trying to write.

In his query, he uses the following to identify databases he wants to pull from.

```
declare @i int, @d nvarchar (3), @max int, @db nvarchar (100), @query nvarchar (max), 
@base_db_name nvarchar(50), @use_loop int;

set @use_loop = 1;
set @i = 276;
set @max = 300;
set @base_db_name = '[$ABC$_DEFG_July_';

/***** Uncomment below to use on a single database *****/
/*
set @use_loop = 0;
set @i = 1;
set @max = 1;
set @db = '[$TML$_AS 4030].dbo.';
*/

/************************************************************
***********************************************************
```

Now from the little I understand, I believe he's finding databases that start with $ABC$_DEFG_July_' and finds them with integer values at the end.

But what I want to do, is replace this so that it finds all databases that have ABCDir at any point in the database name, no matter what other characters are in the name.

Answer (score 0):

You can you sys.databases system table and LIKE operator. Something like this:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    sys.databases
WHERE   name LIKE N'%ABCD%'
```

Comment: would I need to declare any variables like the original query?

Comment: Depends on what you want to do. If you want just database names then this script will work just fine without any additional edits.

Comment: what is the `N` for in `LIKE N'%ABCD%`?

Comment: N is used to indicate that string is unicode. In this particular example u can omit it.